# Хочу при нажатии на кнопку скрывать элемент массива как бы в "disabled"

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Обычный ToDo App проект для себя. С удалением одного элемента массива из списка элементов вроде понятно все. Но не могу понять как реализовать функцию, которая будет изменять один элемент, делая его как бы "disabled", чтобы весь инпут становился прозрачным, и оставались только серый бордер с текстом внутри. Так же при повторном нажатии нужно, чтобы компонент снова становился нормальным.

```js
import TodoForm from "./components/Todos/TodoForm"
import TodoList from "./components/Todos/TodoList"
import "./App.css"

function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = userState([])
    const addTodoHandler = (text) => {
        setTodos([...toods, text])
    }

    const deleteTodoHandler = (index) => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((_, idx) => idx !== index))
    }
    
    const completeTodoHandler = () => {}

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Todo App</h1>
            <todoForm addTodo={addTodoHandler} />
            <todoList
                 todos={todos}
                 deleteTodo={deleteTodoHandler}
                 completeTodo={completeHandler}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Рендер списка компонентов:

```
import Todo from "./Todo"
import styles from "./TodoList.module.css"

function TodoList({ todos, deleteTodo, completeTodo }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.todoListContainer}>
      {!todos.length && <h2>Todo list is empty</h2>}
      {todos.map((todo, index) => (
        <Todo
          key={index}
          todo={todo}
          index={index}
          deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
          completeTodo={completeTodo}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

Сам компонент:

```
import { RiTodoFill } from "react-icons/ri"
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/fa"
import { BsCheckSquareFill } from "react-icons/bs"
import styles from "./Todo.module.css"

function Todo({ todo, index, deleteTodo, completeTodo }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.todo}>
      <RiTodoFill className={styles.todoIcon} />
      <div className={styles.todoText}>{todo}</div>
      <FaTrash
        className={styles.todoIconDelete}
        onClick={() => deleteTodo(index)}
      />
      <BsCheckSquareFill
        className={styles.todoIconComplete}
        onClick={() => completeTodo(index)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При нажатии на что должно это работать? Покажите компонент, который рендерит сам список

Comment: Добавил, при нажатии на иконку BsCheckSquareFill

Comment: Замените скрин текстом... Очень сложно читать картинку

Comment: Из того, что вижу, вам необходимо поменять структуру хранения ваших todos. Сделать их объектами и передавать текущее состояние. Сейчас у вас просто негде передать и сохранить состояние того или иного объекта todos

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду деструктуризацию каждого компонента?

Comment: Нет, вот вы сохраняете в addTodoHandler только текст. Сделайте ваш todo объектом, на подобии {id: Math.random(), enable: true, text: text } При удалении, смотрите не на индекс элемента, а на Id. Когда надо скрыть, меняйте enable и выставляйте нужны класс стиля вашему компоненту. т.е. сделайте так, что бы ваш элемент todo имел свойства

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!